# NSUserDefaults Errors under Swift version 2.0

Tags: xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm having some issues implementing the NSUserDefaults in Swift version 2.0.  My code work fine for Swift v1, but having some issue with v2.  First, the data isn't save once I press the save button and two, my app crashes once I press on the save button.  Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong with my coding?

```
import UIKit

    class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phone: UITextField!  
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!

    @IBAction func btnSave() {

            if name.text == " " {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Data", message: "Missing Name.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            else if phone.text == " " {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Data", message: "Missing Phone Number.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    return
            }

            else if email.text == " " {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Data", message: "Missing Email Address.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            }

            let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

            userDefaults.setObject(name, forKey:"name")
            userDefaults.setObject(phone, forKey:"phone")
            userDefaults.setObject(email, forKey:"email")

            userDefaults.synchronize()
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {

            let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

            userDefaults.setObject(" ", forKey: "name")
            userDefaults.setObject(" ", forKey: "phone")
            userDefaults.setObject(" ", forKey: "email")

            super.viewDidLoad()

        }   
    }
```

Comment: you are setting a new object (single space) every time your view load

Comment: btw there is no way this ever worked with any version of Swift

Comment: The biggest issue (among others) is you are trying to save the UITextField object itself. Use name.text in the IBAction function when saving to persistent storage. You want the string, not the actual textfield.

Comment: @coder ,write userDefaults.synchronize() after userDefaults.setObject(" ", forKey: "email")  in viewDidLoad.Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your UITextfield problem was solved. Now try this to help you get at the information retained from your viewDidLoad function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let nameSaved = userDefaults.objectForKey("name") as? String {
        name.text = nameSaved
    }

    if let phoneSaved = userDefaults.objectForKey("phone") as? String {
        phone.text = phoneSaved
    }

    if let emailSaved = userDefaults.objectForKey("email") as? String {
        email.text = emailSaved
    }
}
```

Put it into viewWillAppear() if you want it called after everytime you move back to your controller.

Comment: Awesome!  That work for me.  Man..the problem has been driving me crazy for the last few days.  Thanks Shen!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save the text fields instead of its text value. You should save its text value

`userDefaults.setObject(name.text ?? " ", forKey:"name")
userDefaults.setObject(phone.text ?? " " , forKey:"phone")
userDefaults.setObject(email.text ?? " ", forKey:"email")`

Comment: Well, it doesn't crash anymore, but the data doesn't retain.  The data still disappear after I leave that page.

Comment: I even changed the  it to userDefaults.setObject(name.text, forKey:"name") and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Coder It does retain, you are just overwriting it. There is no where in the code that you get the object back. You are only setting and not getting. In viewDidLoad, populate the textfield using userDefaults.objectForKey("name") as? String. BUT, use an if let statement. Then you can proceed to pass it into the textfield if its there.

Comment: @coder ,write userDefaults.synchronize() after userDefaults.setObject(" ", forKey: "email")  in viewDidLoad.Hope it helps you.